# TypeError: $(...).circliful is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with a code. I want to import this [statistic circles](http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Animated-Circle-Statistics-Plugin-With-jQuery-Canvas-Circliful.html) library in my web project. I am getting this error:

> TypeError: $(...).circliful is not a function circle.js:2:2

I've imported all files correctly:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/storefront/jquery.circliful.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/storefront/circle.js"></script>
```

Secondly I made my :

```html
<div id="test-circle3"></div>
```

This is the circle.js:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test-circle3").circliful({
        animation: 1,
        animationStep: 6,
        foregroundBorderWidth: 5,
        backgroundBorderWidth: 1,
        percent: 88,
        iconColor: '#3498DB',
        icon: 'f004',
        iconSize: '40',
        iconPosition: 'middle'
    });
});
```

Head section:

```
<head>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/storefront/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/storefront/scrolling_nav.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/storefront/styleswitcher.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/storefront/js.cookie.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Is this included after jQuery?

Comment: Yes it is icluded after jQuery

Comment: Yes, firstly include jquery, always, and then include plugins

Comment: change the order of your includes. jQuery first

Comment: @SeDav jQuery is included in the header file first

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors

Comment: @SeDav <head>
     <script src="/wp-content/themes/storefront/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: Can you look at your html source and cehck that jquery is really before circle plugin?

Comment: Why are there three comments telling the OP to include jQuery first, after the OP stated that he already did so? Anyway, you can check your console’s Network tab to confirm that the `jquery.circliful.min.js` file was found.

Comment: @Xufox probably because weve all seen this sort of error a thousand times, and it is *always* that the imports were the wrong way round and/or missing!

Comment: @Jamiec but I've imported jQuery at the right place! It's loading first in the head section before the other stuff is loading

Comment: @Xufox yes, it's loading

Comment: Include in your question the entire head section of your page.

Comment: So the head includes jQuery, where are you including your plugin? (You're not making this easy on us are you!)

Comment: @Jamiec Imported it! By the way the other stuff is working and I have other pages where I include .js files to in the head are just the important files included for all pages

Comment: @Jamiec I'm including the plugin on a site in wordpress. The head section is another file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129336/discussion-between-jamiec-and-itsodi).

Answer (score 0):

change all js and css include path in your wordpress website like this.

old url

```
<script src="/wp-content/themes/storefront/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

new url

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```